# Paypal shows old version error on express check out , I got my page run first but now shows this error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I doing paypal express checkout in jsp on sandbox  with out using the sdk I am getting the ACK as sucess when generating the token after that when i redirected to sandbox now it shows error message on sandbox as

> You have requested an outdated version of PayPal. This error often results from the use of bookmarks.

This is the Ack response i got

> TOKEN=EC%2d5PT30649GD612951T&TIMESTAMP=2012%2d03%2d04T16%3a44%3a18Z&CORRELATIONID=4ed0e9de9ec8a&ACK=Success&VERSION=84%2e0&BUILD=2571254

I decoded the response using URLDecoder and redirected to the sandbox

> if (ack.equals("Success")) {
>  String logurl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=express-checkout&token="+token;
>                   response.sendRedirect(logurl);
>               }

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and answers

Comment: Please post the exact error message, including the full API response (if it's an API error you're seeing).

Comment: @Robert    After getting the token I redirected the page to sandbox with the token but it shows an error in the sand box like " You have requested an outdated version of PayPal. This error often results from the use of bookmarks."

Comment: Yes, this error simply means the link you're using is invalid. It's not specific to Express Checkout. It's just PayPal's way of returning a '404' page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working and I am answering because i found many one have same error This error occurs mainly  due to any of the samll **errors or changes in your NVP** if you are using it.

I think  **This [link](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/paypal-sample-code/you-have-requested-outdated-version-paypal) will be helps** , deals with "You have requested an outdated version of PayPal"

Comment: ok got it working when i added an _ in redirecting url just before express checkout like this '"sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/…; and if any got an error like this pls refer to this page it willl help x.com/developers/paypal/forums/paypal-sample-code/

Answer (score 3):

If you are receiving this error, it is best to check the url you are redirecting.
Documentation says that the URL is

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout
```

Careful with the **_express-checkout** part. If you are using an ide (like Visual Studio) that marks the urls as links, you might think that it is a space (as it becomes invisible) and at the first error you encounter, you might delete the underscore char.

Comment: I had the same problem and in my case i copied "_express-checkout" without underscore "express-checkout". Added underscore and it worked.

Comment: it saved from headache.